# How to change the default code in new autohotkey scripts?

Tags: autohotkey

I have some code I use to make the script autoreload upon observing changes. How can I include this automatically when I create a new script?

Answer (score 0):

The default "New AutoHotkey Script" file is C:\Windows\ShellNew\Template.ahk

Just edit and save it using Notepad.

source: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=28984